# Executing a shell script on double click

Tags: shell, ubuntu, intellij-idea, scripting

I have a shell script which i constantly use to open my jidea IDE

1. i created a soft link of the script to my desktop which is expected
   to act as a desktop shortcut.
2. But it will also in-turn execute as a
   terminal instance.
3. I tried to disown the terminal instance after it
   was executed, which did not work.

Is there any-other way in which i can execute this as a background process maybe?

Any help is appreciated...
Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: maybe better on askubuntu ...

Answer (score 1):

First be sure your script has the execution permission.

If you are using nautilus here how to fix

- Open nautilus
- go to `Edit > Preferences > Behavior`
- check`Executable text files` and select `Run executable text files when they are opened`